# Extracting Data from a .mdb file to mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, yii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access from PHP to .mdb file on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291388/access-from-php-to-mdb-file-on-ubuntu)

Hi I'm developing a webstore using the php framework yii..

I want to upload a .mdb file to our system, and extract data from it and insert into mysql database..

Is there anyway of doin this?

It'll be great if someone could help me out.

Thanks

Comment: check here:   http://devzone.zend.com/1315/reading-access-databases-with-php-and-pecl/

Comment: check 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722544/how-can-i-convert-an-mdb-access-file-to-mysql-or-plain-sql-file

Comment: @cutebabs I think those are manual tools, and OP is looking for something that can be automated

Answer (score 6):

Use odbc_connect() function using a database source name (DSN). Alternatively, a DSN-less connection string can be used.

**DSN-less connections**

if no password, leave username as "sa" and password blank.

```
$conn = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mdb_file", $user, $password);
```

**To Connect with DSN**

from *http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_db_odbc.asp*

Open the Administrative Tools icon in your Control Panel
Double-click on the Data Sources (ODBC) icon inside.
Choose the System DSN tab.
Click on Add in the System DSN tab.
Select the Microsoft Access Driver. Click Finish.
In the next screen, click Select to locate the database.
Give the database a Data Source Name (DSN).
Click OK.

```
$conn = odbc_connect($dsn_name, $user, $password);
```

Query:

```
$res = odbc_exec($conn, "select * from table");
```

List results:

```
while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($res) ) { 
    print_r($row); 
}
```

More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.uodbc.php

Comment: k..but can i do this after uploading the file and initializing it to $mdb_file ??

Comment: Yes, it should work fine. Let me know.

Comment: thanks i will try it and let u know ...

Comment: okay i tried what you suggested and its giving a sql error saying 
 SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect

do i need to import anything in order to use the odbc functions?

Comment: Are you running the code on a windows machine?

Comment: yes i am and im using a php framework called yii

Comment: any idea why im getting that error?

Comment: I edited my answer, check above. Use a DSN

Answer (score 0):

read the data from mdb to csv

read from csv  and insert into mysql

Comment: like the answer if this helps

Comment: is there a way of converting the .mdb file to .csv using yii or php?