# PDO connection using MDBtool linux

Tags: php, linux, mdbtools

hello everyone just wondering why its not working,
im trying to INSERT data to MS access file (.MDB)
 OS is GNU-Unix/Linux,

in my odbcinst.ini

```
[mdb]
Description = MDB Tools ODBC
Driver = /ble/blee/libmdbodbc.so.0
Setup =
FileUsage =
CPTimeout =
CPReuse =
```

and in my odbc.ini

```
[test1]
Description = Microsoft Access Try DB
Driver = mdb
Database = /bla/blaa/blaaa/Yeah.MDB
Servername = localhost
```

in my test.php

```
$conn = new PDO("odbc:DSN=test1;");
$data = $conn->prepare("select  * from table1");
$data->execute();
$done= $data->fetch();
```

using this script i retrieve data 
but when im going to INSERT/DELETE into .mdb

```
$conn = new PDO("odbc:DSN=test1;");
$data = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table1(abcd, efgh, ijkl) values('aaaa', 'bbbb', ccc)");
$data->execute();
```

nothing happen =);
but can't figure out why i can retrieve but not insert?

 thanks for reading 
tee hee hee~~ 
btw: im not sure how to use mdbtools., 
I simply just used ->libmdbodbc.so.0 
and setup my odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini for my code :)

if mdbtools is just for retrieving??
i guess there's no **free** tools out there which can help me to perform  insert statement , just like this problem --> [Access from PHP to .mdb file on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291388/access-from-php-to-mdb-file-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

I have previously faced the same problem. On the [mdbtools](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/) website, it notes:

> MDB Tools currently has read-only support

So you can only use "SELECT" statements with this particular driver.